# Is it possible to call default implementations of interfaces with Mockito's doCallRealMethod?

Tags: mockito

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface ISomething {

    default int doStuff() {
        return 2 * getValue();
    }

    int getValue();
}
```

When I now mock this interface like this:

```
@Mock
private ISomething _something;

@Before
public void setup() {
    doCallRealMethod().when(_something).doStuff();
}
```

and try to test the doStuff() method like the following:

```
@Test
public void testDoStuff() {
    when(_something.getValue()).thenReturn(42);
    assertThat("doStuff() returns 84", _something.doStuff(), is(84));
}
```

I expect the test to succeed, but I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Cannot call real method on java interface. Interface does not have any implementation!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking concrete classes.
```

I tried subclassing `ISomething` with an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Something implements ISomething {
}
```

and mock this class like above. With this approach, I get the same.

Does Mockito not support calling default implementations?

Answer (score 3):

That's correct.  The current version of Mockito doesn't support this.  You could [raise a feature request here](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/list).  Do note that it seems to be related to issue 456 which was fixed in release 1.10.0, so please make sure you test this in the latest version first.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a project using Mockito 1.9.5 and ran into the same issue that you found.  We couldn't upgrade Mockito because of the way our build server worked.  The problem we ran into was when we were writing unit tests for the concrete subclasses, as we couldn't stub out or include the default methods from the interface in our mock objects (so slightly different from your example).

Here is an example subclass using your model:

```
public class ConcreteSomething implements ISomething {

    @Override
    int getValue()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Then in the unit test class, we explicitly made a private inner class.  This class overrode all the default methods of the concrete class under test (i.e. `ConcreteSomething`) with the interface's default implementation.  So in this example, something like:

```
private class ConcreteSomethingDefaultImpl extends ConcreteSomething {

    @Override
    int doStuff() {
        return super.doStuff();
    }
}
```

For us, a mock made using `mock(ConcreteSomething.class)` couldn't have it's default methods called using `doCallRealMethod()`, but `mock(ConcreteSomethingDefaultImpl.class)` could, and more importantly, it was the default implementation code in the interface that was being used.

I hope that helps anyone else who is constrained to use a particular version of Mockito.